# ¿Cómo hacer un upsert con Room en kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, room

ya investigue en ingles me sale esta opción [android-room-persistence-library-upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677230/android-room-persistence-library-upsert) lo modifique un poco y me quedo asi:

```kotlin
    @Dao
    interface BloqueDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM bloque")
        suspend fun getAll(): List<bloque>

        @Query("UPDATE bloque SET act=1 WHERE idfin=:finc")
        suspend fun prevSetUp(finc : Int)

        @Insert( onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        suspend fun insertAll(vararg bloques: bloque?)

        @Update
        suspend fun update(vararg bloques: bloque?)

        @Delete
        suspend fun delete(blo: bloque)

        @Transaction
        suspend fun upsert(vararg bloques: bloque?) {
            val insertResult = insertAll(*bloques)
            if(insertResult is List<Long>){
                val updateList: MutableList<bloque?> = ArrayList()
                for (i in insertResult.indices)
                    if (insertResult[i] == -1L)
                        updateList.add(bloques[i])
                if (updateList.isNotEmpty())
                    update(*updateList.toTypedArray())
            }else if (insertResult == -1L)
                update(bloques[0])

        }
    }
```

el problema esta en que kotlin me dice ***Incompatible types: `List<Long>` and Unit.*** pero la documentación de la biblioteca de room dice:

> Si el método @Insert recibe solo 1 parámetro, puede mostrar un long, que es el nuevo rowId para el elemento insertado. Si el parámetro es un arreglo o una colección, debería mostrar long[] o List

este error me sale antes de compilarlo, si le digo que la función **insertAll** devuelve `Any` me sale otro error pero en la depuración

**imagen del error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**descripción del error**

> Cannot check for instance of erased type: List. Incompatible
> types: List and Unit.

##### SOLUCION

---

se deben crear las funciones por separado

```kotlin
    @Dao
    interface BloqueDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM bloque")
        suspend fun getAll(): List<bloque>

        @Query("UPDATE bloque SET act=1 WHERE idfin=:finc")
        suspend fun prevSetUp(finc : Int)

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        suspend fun insert(bloq: bloque) : Long

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
        suspend fun insertAll(bloques: List<bloque>) : List<Long>
        @Update
        suspend fun update(vararg bloques: bloque)

        @Delete
        suspend fun delete(blo: bloque)

        @Transaction
        suspend fun upsert(bloq: bloque) = insert(bloq).takeIf { it == -1L }.run { update(bloq) }

        @Transaction
        suspend fun upsert(bloques: List<bloque>) = insertAll(bloques)
        .withIndex()
        .filter { it.value == -1L }
        .map { bloques[it.index] }
        .let { if (it.isNotEmpty()) update(*it.toTypedArray()) }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lee detenidamente la documentación

> Si el método `@Insert` recibe solo 1 parámetro, **puede** mostrar un `long`,
> que es el nuevo `rowId` para el elemento insertado. Si el parámetro es
> un arreglo o una colección, debería mostrar `long[]` o `List<Long>`.

La palabra clave es "*puede*". Esto significa que, **si quieres**, puedes hacer que retorne un `Long`. Pero tu función `insertAll` la definiste así

```
suspend fun insertAll(vararg bloques: bloque?)
```

En Kotlin si no indicas el return type de una función, se considera que es `Unit`. Es decir que para que retorne una `List<Long>` debes especificarlo explicitamente

```
suspend fun insertAll(vararg bloques: bloque?): List<Long>
```

Aunque hay algunas cosas que deberías tener en cuenta. Por convención, los nombres de las clases deben comenzar con mayúscula. Es decir que no debe llamarse `bloque` sino `Bloque`. Tampoco debe ser nullable porque no funciona con valores nulos. Y el uso de `vararg` tampoco es muy recomendable en este caso. Supongo que lo usas para que la misma función inserte uno o varios elementos pero esto puede ser confuso. Es preferible dividirla en `insert` e `insertAll`. De esto modo separas las responsabilidades y consigues que el nombre describa correctamente el comportamiento de la función.

Siguiendo las buenas prácticas debería quedar así

```
suspend fun insertAll(bloques: List<Bloque>): List<Long>
```

Pero nada de esto es necesario porque Room ya tiene una implementación de "*upsert*". Simplemente debes usar la anotación `@Insert` con el argumento [OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy#REPLACE)

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun upsert(bloques: List<Bloque>)
```

Si de todos modos quieres escribir tu propia implementación, deberías reemplazar ese código (que parece una conversión automática de Java a Kotlin) por algo más idiomatico. Esto es exactamente lo mismo que tenías pero usando kotlin apropiadamente

```
@Transaction
suspend fun upsert(bloques: List<Bloque>) = insertAll(bloques)
    .withIndex()
    .filter { it.value == -1L }
    .map { bloques[it.index] }
    .let { if (it.isNotEmpty()) updateAll(it) }
```

Comment: cuando estaba investigando tambien encontre esta forma de resolverlo solo pense que había otra alternativa

Comment: en cuanto a las otras dos formas si no las había contemplado, el replace no me sirve por que tengo llaves foráneas y lo que hace es eliminar y luego insertar la foreign key no dejaria, por eso solo me sirve actualizar